# Connect to MySQL in MySQL workbench failed

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

In windows console, I can connect to MySQL with user `root`, but when I'm trying to connect to MySQL in [mysql-workbench](/questions/tagged/mysql-workbench), I failed. Got message:

> `Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

Where is the problem? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you try resetting password through windows console and then reconnect workbench?

Comment: when u connect using console what is your hostname?your ip or localhost?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like  your username / password is not matching

Comment: I don't think so. Because I can login in windows console with the same username / password

Comment: Looks like password is not transmitted to the sql